# Selecting the first child with a specific class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to select **only** the first `box--highlight`.

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="box "></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="box box--highlight"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="box box--highlight"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="box "></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I was trying around with the adjacent siblings combinator but it did not work as expected

```css
li .box--highlight + li .box--highlight {
  color: green;
}
```

Is this even possible? I was wondering if the answer is already to select the parent selector (which is not possible of course): [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: With Javascript, Yes!

Comment: This can be done provided the DOM order does not change later. `li:nth-child(2) .box--highlight { color: green; }`

Comment: Can't you give the classes to the `li` element instead?

Comment: @m4n0 I am looking for a CSS-only approach though. I can edit the html but then I end up without ```li``` elements and that would not be good semantics wise. The order of items will change, so your suggestion would not work.

Comment: @alihmd this is using a scroll-to js plugin which only accepts ```a``` elements unfortunately.

Comment: CSS cannot do it with that structure, send the class to the parent, then you can set and reset a style fromthere, else javascript.

Comment: the shortest way in js i can think off is something alike : `let myfirstboxclassed=document.querySelector('.box--highlight');
myfirstboxclassed.classList.add('styleMe');` where you can style the first class it finds with `.styleMe{/*style*/}`  here is a live example : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qBNrZeZ

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments above: this is not possible with pure CSS.

My workaround is now to remove the `li` element.